# Can sqlite be an inmemory database also?

Tags: sql, sqlite, nunit

A bit confused, I was watching some video where some guy was using sqllite as an in-memory database.  From the sqllite.org site it seems as though it is a real db?

Can it be both or is the in-memory db that I saw something else? (used with NUnit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a [read of this](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

Sqlite is a real embedded DB which is used in lots and lots of places (including the iphone and firefox) the apis allow you to specify if you want to hold your db in memory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just use `":memory:"` as the database path.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be either an in-memory or an on-disk database. Use it as normal, but with a filename of :memory: to stop it from writing to disk.